# Problem with Bibliography Language English (and) instead of German (und)

Tags: bibliographies, german, zotero

I'm trying to switch the language in the bibliography to german, but so far I had no luck with all the hints from the internet.

Here is the code in overleaf, I'm using:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%% Entspricht Zeilenabstand 1.5 in Word
\linespread{1.25}

%% für Querformat
\usepackage{lscape}

%% Rotation des Textes
\usepackage{graphicx}

%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman]{datetime} 
\usepackage{babelbib}
%\usepackage{babelbib}
\newdateformat{myformat}{\THEDAY{. }\monthnamengerman[\THEMONTH] \THEYEAR}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx} % Times New Roman ähnliche Schrift
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} %% Für Unterstrich (\Uline)
\newcommand\tab[1][1cm]{\hspace*{#1}} %% für Tabluator (\tab)
%\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\referencesname}{Referenz} }
\usepackage{float} %%Bildpositionierung
\restylefloat{figure} %Bildpositionierung
%%Querverweise  
\usepackage{prettyref}
\usepackage{titleref}
%%% Für Abschnitt %%%
\newrefformat{sec}{Abschnitt~\ref{#1}}
%%\newrefformat{sec}{Abschnitt~\ref{#1}\ auf Seite \pageref{#1}}
%%% Für nur Abschnitte %%%
\newrefformat{sec1}{~\ref{#1}}
%%% Für Abbildungen %%%
\newrefformat{fig}{Abbildung~\ref{#1}\ auf Seite \pageref{#1}}
%%% Für Abbildung %%% 
\newrefformat{fig1}{Abbildung~\ref{#1}}
\newrefformat{tab}{Tabelle~\ref{#1}\ auf Seite \pageref{#1}}
\newrefformat{tab1}{Tabelle~\ref{#1}}
%%% Parallele Grafiken %%%
\usepackage{subfigure} 

%% Sets page size and margins
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

%% Useful packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
%% Hyperlink aktiviert / deaktiviert
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
% URL Zeilenumbruch 
\apptocmd{\UrlBreaks}{\do\f\do\m}{}{}

% glossary
\usepackage[xindy={language=german,codepage=utf8}]{glossaries}
\setglossarystyle{treehypergroup}
\input{glossary}
\makeglossaries
%End glossary

%comments
\usepackage{comment}
%end comments

\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Abb.}}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tab.}}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Inhaltsverzeichnis} }
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\glossaryname}{Glossar} }
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\refname}{Literaturverzeichnis} }
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Tabellenverzeichnis}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

....

%Literaturverzeichnis
\bibliographystyle{alphaurl}
%\bibliographystyle{gerplain}% or babplain-fl
%\bibliographystyle{gerplain} 
%\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{Zotero.bib}
\pagebreak
\section*{Anhang}
\end{document}
```

eg: alphaurl -> works basically, but I get wrong AND instead of UND between two autors

unsrtdin -> Bibliography (?) Error:

[image]

Do you have any hints that could work in this setup? Thanks!!

Comment: @Luke: The `bibliographystyle` you chose seems to be incompatible with the language specifications of `babelbib`. Would switching to `biblatex` be an option for you?

Comment: Thanks @leandriis, I now get an biblatex error "incompatible package ucs" -> seems like \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} is used to solve that... but this leads to an other error: Package biblatex Error: File 'main.bbl' not created by biblatex

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with using the comibination:

```
% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman]{datetime} 
\usepackage{babelbib}
```

... at the end, inserting:

```
\bibliographystyle{alphadin} 
\bibliography{Zotero.bib}
```

With this style, there are no AND used between authors at all...
So it's kind of a workaround.

HTH Luke

Comment: did you try to load `polyglossia` package and then use `\setmainlanguage{german}`? in that case you must compile your document using `xelatex` or `lualatex` engine